# Como tratar barra invertida duplicada no json

Tags: php

Qual a melhor alternativa para remover as \ colocadas em formulários pelo usuário?

Exemplo através dos dados recebidos pelo usuário crio um json

```
{
"tags": "\\\u00E7"
}
```

Obviamente o json não irá ler poís está duplicado, ele não consegue identificar qual caractere unicode é.

Qual a melhor forma de tratar isso, para que ele receba somente uma barra invertida, independentemente de quantas o usuário colocar no `form`?

Comment: Como não? Usando `echo json_decode('{"tags": "\u00E7" }')->tags;` resulta em `ç`, que é o correto (`"\u{00E7}" === json_decode('{"tags": "\u00E7" }')->tags;` é `1`).

Comment: Se pegar um exemplo em que há varios \\\ não funciona : exemplo $texto = '{"tags": "Anima\\u00E7\\\\\\\\\\\\u00F5Es"}';

echo json_decode($texto)->tags;

Comment: Não funciona porque está escapado incorretamente, cada `\\` é um `\`. Para que ele deve ter apenas o `\u00E7` e depois deveria de ter 6x `\` + `\00F5Es`. O seu problema está na hora de formatar o JSON, isto não está presente na sua pergunta, então não há como resolver.

Comment: @Gabriel, e se você fizer um `str_replace()` pra retirar todas as \ que vierem? Isso te ajudaria? Caso sim, consigo te mandar um exemplo da função.

Comment: Você pode usar `echo json_encode(['tags' => '/\ção']);` terá como resultado o `{"tags":"\/\\\u00e7\u00e3o"}`, formatado corretamente. Lembre-se que deve está usando UTF-8.

Comment: @JaksonFischer sim, ajudaria, um preg_replace seria mais util , mas não consegui fazer a expressao regular

Comment: @Gabriel, respondido. Peço para que se a pergunta for útil, marque-a como correto por favor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Como pedido no seu comentário, segue um exemplo de substituição com o `str_replace()`.

```
$var = "C\o\i\s\a";

//$replace = str_replace('\', '/', $var);

echo str_replace('\\', '', $var)

//Saída: Coisa.
```

---

**Note que:**

Ao utilizar a `\` para ser substituída, teremos que adicionar uma `\` adicional, para que o PHP entenda que ele deverá procurar esta `\` e que ela não faz parte do seu código.

A função `str_replace()` tem como função substituir valores.

Os parâmetros para o seu uso são:

`str_replace("busca", "troca", "conteúdo")`

Leia sobre o [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php) no php.net.

Segue um [exemplo funcional](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/yymc-kxur) no phpfiddle.

Comment: foi mais util preg_replace('/(\\\)\1+/', '$1', $object);

Comment: Então isto não resolveu?

Comment: Resolvi com preg_replace